# Move Core Data from simulator to device

Tags: iphone, core-data, build-process

First i would apologize for the question as there are answers out there but as this is my first project i do not really understand the explanations how to do this.

I have an application that uses Core Data, which works on the simulator but not when i generate it on my device. The app starts but it seems like the Core Data is empty. I guess i need to move the DB into the device.

Would someone nice be able to, in a simple way, explain how I fix this?

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

I downloaded "iPhone Explorer" (http://www.macroplant.com/iphoneexplorer/) and manually removed the two instances of the DB on the actual device and re-run the app and all finally worked.

Comment: Do you have a sqlite db setup which should be shipped with the app?

Comment: well, I have created a Core Data setup (.xcdatamodeld) that i access from the application it is sqlite if that is what you mean?

Comment: You say, that your Core Data is empty on the device, what does that exactly mean? What's in the simulator what's not there on the device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you populate the sqlite generated by Core Data (found in the simulator folder) and want to add to the main bundle of your project to load on application startup, then please see the instructions on the following website:

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/08/core-data-starting-data.html

This basically checks for the pre-populated DB. If not found, it creates one as normally done when on first launch of a application which uses Core Data.